# Find duplicates with same number sequence

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to filter through loads of user data to find duplicate accounts. The best way to find identify the users are telephone numbers.
Unfortunately the numbers are not saved in the same format, nor do all the cells have the same amount of digits. See below:

+1 912 555 1234
001 912 5551234
(912) 5551234
912 5551234
912-555-1234

Is there anyway to just duplicate search for a certain sequence? So in this case 5551234.

I could just remove all the special signs (brackets, dashes, spaces etc.) manually with a simple "search and replace", right? But still the cells would have different amount of digits which is why normal duplicate search does not work.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Are you working in an environment that would allow you to use VBA @LeGunt1801 ? You haven't tagged it, and I know some workplaces lock down that functionality for security reasons. It would make your life a lot easier here though, if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can't use VBA, I've put together a quick series of functions to deal with all the examples you have above. It may not be comprehensive, but you'll get the general idea. Put all of the below code into row 2 of a spreadsheet (so you can use headings if you wish)

```
Column A: Tel numbers
Column B (remove whitespace): =SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(32),"")
Column C (remove brackets and dashes): =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2, CHAR(40),""), CHAR(41),""),CHAR(45),"")
Column D (replace +1 with 0): =IF(LEFT(C2,1)="+","0"&RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-2),C2)
Column E (replace 001 with 0): =IF(LEFT(D2,3)="001","0"&RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-3),D2)
Column F (ensure leading 0): =IF(LEFT(E2,1)="0",E2,"0"&E2)
```

Just copy/paste the cells down, and all the numbers used in your example will have the same format (in column F).

Note that columns B/C could be combined easily into a single column, but I've left them separated to make it easier to understand how it works. The combined column would be 
    =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(32),""), CHAR(40),""), CHAR(41),""),CHAR(45),"")

If you need to remove any more special characters (in addition to the brackets and dashes) you can find all the ascii codes used by the SUBSTITUTE function in [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/).